# JQuery Mobile OSM div is set to 0% height automatically even though my CSS has it set to 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using Open Street Maps in a JQuery Mobile app. The map is on its own page and appears when the user clicks the  link to the page. The map code works but the div the map is in is automatically being set to height:0% when in my CSS I have 100%. I can use inspect element in chrome to manually change the height of the div to 100% and the map shows properly. (Also after clicking the link the map flashes for a brief moment and then disappears so something is forcing it back to 0% after the link is clicked for some reason)

edit: I have tried using !important but that did not work.

Comment: @Dev'Hamz That would be difficult considering the app is near completion and really long at this point.  I'm not sure what code I can really show to be honest.

Comment: Humm okay .. what version of jQuery use you ?

Comment: JQuery mobile 1.4.1 JQuery core 1.9.1

Comment: If i see at least your website i'll can do something.. it seems like your div is not completely charged on the right time... but again without any code it's really complicated...

Comment: Well it's an app using phonegap. If you really want me to I can give you a link to just download my entire source code. What code do you need to see exactly? Its just a link to another page which has the map in it. Not sure what code there is to show you there.

Comment: Try to give to your div a 500 pixels maybe it's set to 0 because the div parent doesn't have contains..

Comment: @Dev'Hamz I do not understand what you mean. It is definatley a problem with JQM because When I click the link the map div height is set to 100% and shows for a split second and then is immediately set back to 0%. So something is changing it but I can't figure out what. Sorry if I cant provide a code example I understand it's difficult to help without code, I just don't really know what to show you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!important` like that :

```
height: 100% !important
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that I did try that to no avail.